# How to match a string before something or the end of line?

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to match the following string:

```
" 4/abc def"
```

from

```
" 4/abc def 5/abc"
```

or

```
" 4/abc def"
```

So far I managed to build this regex:

```
(?<MyGroup> 4\/(.+)(?=(?: \d\/)))
```

and I tried to make the lookahead optional `?` or add a `|$` but then it catches everything. Can I somehow make the `5/abc` optional?

I've tried it with these expressions but they didn't work for both cases:

```
(?<MyGroup> 4\/(.+)(?=(?: \d\/)?))
(?<MyGroup> 4\/(.+)(?=(?: \d\/|$)))
```

[SAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/gW9gP3/2)

EDIT:

I am forced to use the period because there can by any character. It's a free-text field.

Comment: for end of line matching you have str.endsWith("string")

Comment: EndsWith won't work here because it's a part of a bigger expression with several optional fields.

Comment: OK - so this: `<MyGroup>` looks like you have XML. Do you have XML? Because if so, regex parsing just doesn't work very well, but XML parsing works brilliantly.

Comment: @Sobrique That is a named capturing group in regex.

Comment: i am not talking about your data format spec formatting. As far as string is concerned it should not be a problem, ofcourse i am talking only about the end of line matching

Comment: @Sobrique: `<MyGroup>` is not XML. It's a named regex group so that I don't have to use indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.+` lazy by adding a `?` and add the alternation to `$`

```
(?<MyGroup> 4\/(.+?)(?=(?: \d\/)|$))
```

- `(.+?)` The lazy matching causes the regex engine to stop once it sees the first `\d/` than continuing to the end of the string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gW9gP3/4)

Comment: Unfortunately there can be any character. That's why I took the ".". Sorry for not mentioning this in my question. I'll update it.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have corrected my answer. Do check if meets your requirements.

Comment: I totaly forgot about the lazy operator. Thx, now it does what it should :)

Comment: @t3chb0t Even I was burning my head for last 20 mins :)